# FFmpeg4Android: How to select videos from gallery?

Tags: android, android-intent, video, ffmpeg

I have created an app using FFmpeg4Android library. I would like to add watermark into videos using ffmpeg. Command for adding watermark is working fine but the coding has pre-fixed video name in the command. I would like to choose videos from gallery folder and then add watermark to the videos. I do not know how to add intent for choosing videos with FFmpeg. I have tried to add the intent like this replacing the in.mp4 with PICK_FROM_GALLERY intent:

```
 private void runTranscodingUsingLoader() {
    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "runTranscodingUsingLoader started...");

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)ProgressBarExample.this.getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "VK_LOCK");
    Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "Acquire wake lock");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);


    String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg","-y" ,"-i", String.valueOf(PICK_FROM_GALLERY),"-strict","experimental",
            "-vf", "movie=/sdcard/videokit/watermark.png [watermark];" +
            " [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]","-s",
            "320x240","-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4","-ab",
            "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "/sdcard/videokit/out1.mp4"};
```

It opens the gallery but the watermarking command doesnt get executed in the selected video. Can someone help me to resolve this issue. I could not find proper references/examples regarding this. My full coding is as follows.

```
public class ProgressBarExample extends Activity  {

public ProgressDialog progressBar;

String workFolder = null;
String demoVideoFolder = null;
String demoVideoPath = null;
String vkLogPath = null;
LoadJNI vk;
private final int STOP_TRANSCODING_MSG = -1;
private final int FINISHED_TRANSCODING_MSG = 0;
private boolean commandValidationFailedFlag = false;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

private void runTranscodingUsingLoader() {
    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "runTranscodingUsingLoader started...");

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)ProgressBarExample.this.getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "VK_LOCK");
    Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "Acquire wake lock");
    wakeLock.acquire();




    String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg","-y" ,"-i", "/sdcard/videokit/in.mp4","-strict","experimental",
            "-vf", "movie=/sdcard/videokit/watermark.png [watermark];" +
            " [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]","-s",
            "320x240","-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4","-ab",
            "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "/sdcard/videokit/out1.mp4"};
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    vk = new LoadJNI();
    try {
        // running complex command with validation
        vk.run(complexCommand, workFolder, getApplicationContext());

        // running without command validation
        //vk.run(complexCommand, workFolder, getApplicationContext(), false);

        // running regular command with validation
        //vk.run(GeneralUtils.utilConvertToComplex(commandStr), workFolder, getApplicationContext());

        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "vk.run finished.");
        // copying vk.log (internal native log) to the videokit folder
        GeneralUtils.copyFileToFolder(vkLogPath, demoVideoFolder);

    } catch (CommandValidationException e) {
        Log.e(Prefs.TAG, "vk run exeption.", e);
        commandValidationFailedFlag = true;

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e(Prefs.TAG, "vk run exeption.", e);
    }
    finally {
        if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.release();
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "Wake lock released");
        }
        else{
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "Wake lock is already released, doing nothing");
        }
    }

    // finished Toast
    String rc = null;
    if (commandValidationFailedFlag) {
        rc = "Command Vaidation Failed";
    }
    else {
        rc = GeneralUtils.getReturnCodeFromLog(vkLogPath);
    }
    final String status = rc;
    ProgressBarExample.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ProgressBarExample.this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (status.equals("Transcoding Status: Failed")) {
                Toast.makeText(ProgressBarExample.this, "Check: " + vkLogPath + " for more information.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "onCreate ffmpeg4android ProgressBarExample");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ffmpeg_demo_client_2);

    demoVideoFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/videokit/";
    demoVideoPath = demoVideoFolder + "in.mp4";

    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, getString(R.string.app_name) + " version: " + GeneralUtils.getVersionName(getApplicationContext()) );

    Button invoke =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.invokeButton);
    invoke.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "run clicked.");
            runTranscoding();
        }
    });

    workFolder = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/";
    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "workFolder (license and logs location) path: " + workFolder);
    vkLogPath = workFolder + "vk.log";
    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "vk log (native log) path: " + vkLogPath);
    GeneralUtils.copyLicenseFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded(this, workFolder);
    GeneralUtils.copyDemoVideoFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded(this, demoVideoFolder);
    int rc = GeneralUtils.isLicenseValid(getApplicationContext(), workFolder);
    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "License check RC: " + rc);
}



private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "Handler got message");
        if (progressBar != null) {
            progressBar.dismiss();

            // stopping the transcoding native
            if (msg.what == STOP_TRANSCODING_MSG) {
                Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "Got cancel message, calling fexit");
                vk.fExit(getApplicationContext());


            }
        }
    }
};

public void runTranscoding() {
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(ProgressBarExample.this);
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressBar.setTitle("FFmpeg4Android Direct JNI");
    progressBar.setMessage("Press the cancel button to end the operation");
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);

    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(STOP_TRANSCODING_MSG);
        }
    });

    progressBar.show();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(Prefs.TAG,"Worker started");
            try {
                //sleep(5000);
                runTranscodingUsingLoader();
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(FINISHED_TRANSCODING_MSG);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("threadmessage",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();

    // Progress update thread
    new Thread() {
        ProgressCalculator pc = new ProgressCalculator(vkLogPath);
        public void run() {
            Log.d(Prefs.TAG,"Progress update started");
            int progress = -1;
            try {
                while (true) {
                    sleep(300);
                    progress = pc.calcProgress();
                    if (progress != 0 && progress < 100) {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    }
                    else if (progress == 100) {
                        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "==== progress is 100, exiting Progress update thread");
                        pc.initCalcParamsForNextInter();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("threadmessage",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

}
```

Any help/guidance would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg is not used for picking up the video from gallery or any where.
 But it is used for the processing on video(s) of given path so that you need to pick the video according to user choice using default android video picker through intent. After the `onActivityResult(...)` method you will get path of that selected video then after getting this video path you can pass this path to appropriate ffmpeg command for video processing.

Comment: means i should pass like the video uri from the onActivityResult() to ffmpeg is it? @santoXme

Comment: you can get the absolute path form URI  and  than you have to pass that absolute path to ffmpeg...

Comment: okay thank you so much @santoXme.. i will try to do as you suggested.